# ESP32 Cam: A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, esp32

I have an ESP32-Cam AIThinker and everytime I try to upload (File > Examples > ESP32 > Camera), I always get this error everytime: 
`A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header.`

I've been following YouTube tutorials but none just seem to work for me :(

[Here are my upload settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caehd.png) At the time of writing, I am using Arduino IDE 1.8.15 and esp32 board version 1.0.6.
**I have tried:**

- Using FTDI232 to upload 
  [Pinout Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHNSY.png)
- Using Arduino to upload 
  [Pinout Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBZcF.png)
- Using ESP32-CAM-MB that came with the ESP32-Cam I bought.
- Pressing the RST button while and before uploading (also waiting for the "connection" text to appear then pressing RST).
- Switching between 3.3v and 5v, still the same error.
- Switching between QIO and DIO flash mode.
- Swapping RX and TX.

Though I didn't get any errors uploading using the ESP32-CAM-MB, I was stuck on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhXrA.png) and it wouldn't show me IP to where I can access the camera.

I am new to this so please take it easy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: Remove the GPIO0 and GND short after uploading the code and press the RST button.

Comment: No luck, still the same problem.

Comment: Select the board: AI Thinker ESP32-CAM in your upload settings. Also, try using an external power source for powering the ESP32.

Comment: I tried uploading using AIThinker as the board. Still no luck :( And what exactly do you mean by powering the ESP32Cam via an external power source?

Answer (score 0):

Press the Reset (or Boot in some boards) button and keep it pressed until you see that the code is being written (uploaded) on the board.